# Java Scripting Interpreter

Tags: java, scripting, interpreter

I am thinking about building a project, that in the name of custom expanding (time of execution doesn't really mean too much) and will control arrays of custom objects within the program providing all/most the object data for modification by the script.

Now I was wondering if there was any library for java that would allow for perhaps a javascript style of scripting that would do that, or would it perhaps be easier to write a simple line-by-line interpretation without too much internal processing (object data and simple function calls).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)? Per the link...

> Rhino is an open-source implementation of JavaScript written entirely
>   in Java. **It is typically embedded into Java applications to provide
>   scripting to end users.**

Comment: Ace's. Cheer's, I didn't know what to search for in Google